# Error: static assertion failed on compiling compiler-rt ASAN runtime for aarch64_be

Tags: clang, arm64, address-sanitizer

I am using RTOS/arm64be(GNU 7.3.0) to corss build CLANG compiler-rt ASAN runtime lib. And I get an error like this:

```
121 In file included from /cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_linux.cpp:21:0:
122 /cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:332:30: error: static assertion failed
123  #define COMPILER_CHECK(pred) static_assert(pred, "")
128 /cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_linux.cpp:72:1: note: in expansion of macro 'COMPILER_CHECK'
129  COMPILER_CHECK(struct_kernel_stat_sz == sizeof(struct stat));
```

I have checked struct_kernel_stat_sz in lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.h:

```
lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.h：74 #elif defined(__aarch64__)
lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.h：75 const unsigned struct_kernel_stat_sz = 128;
lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.h：76 const unsigned struct_kernel_stat64_sz = 104;
```

obviously struct_kernel_stat_sz takes 128 in my case.
I also have checked asm/stat.h in my sysroot(RTOS/**/arm64be/sdkilp32) for stat definition and I did not find any architecture related MACRO controlling the build flow.

Additionly, here list my compilation command line

```
aarch64_be-linux -gnu-g++ -Dasan_EXPORTS -I/cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/. -I/cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common -I/cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan  -fPIC -Wall -std=c++14 -Wno-unused-parameter -fpermissive -nodefaultlibs -Wl,-z,text -Wl,--version-script,/cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/build/lib/asan/clang_rt.asan-dynamic-x86_64.vers -Wl,-z,    gnu-version-script-compat-shared -DARCH=arm -mabi=ilp32 -march=armv8-a -mbig-endian -D__ARCH_WANT_SYSCALL_OFF_T -D__ILP32__ -fstack-protector-strong --sysroot=${TOOL_PATH}/sdkilp32 -o CMakeFiles/asan.dir/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cpp.o -c /cdev/ASAN/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cpp
```

Comment: Seems LLVM sanitizer missing support for AArch64 ILP32, sizeof(struct stat) == 80 in AArch64 ILP32

Comment: https://patches.linaro.org/patch/129368/ sloves the issue.